# How to allow only vertical and horizontal swipe in custom UICollectionViewLayout

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionviewlayout

please help me with this issue , i am following this [tutorial](https://www.credera.com/blog/mobile-applications-and-web/building-a-multi-directional-uicollectionview-in-swift/) to make a custom UICollectionViewLayout were the user can swipe horizontally to navigate thru sections and vertically to show items.

My problem is that i only want the user to swipe vertically or horizontally not freely thru the UICollectionView. Any ideas on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code

```
import UIKit

class moviesLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {

let CELL_HEIGHT = 307.0
let CELL_WIDTH  = 204.0

var cellAttrDict = Dictionary<NSIndexPath, UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes>()

var contentSize = CGSizeZero

var dataSourceDidUpdate = true

override func collectionViewContentSize() -> CGSize {

    return contentSize
}

override func prepareLayout() {

    if collectionView?.numberOfSections() > 0 {
        for section in 0...collectionView!.numberOfSections()-1 {
            if collectionView?.numberOfItemsInSection(section) > 0 {
                for item in 0...collectionView!.numberOfItemsInSection(section)-1 {
                            let cellIndex = NSIndexPath(forItem: item, inSection: section)
                            let xPos = Double(item) * CELL_WIDTH
                            let yPos = Double(section) * CELL_HEIGHT

                            var cellAttributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWithIndexPath: cellIndex)
                            cellAttributes.frame = CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: CELL_WIDTH, height: CELL_HEIGHT)
                            cellAttributes.zIndex = 1
                            cellAttrDict[cellIndex] = cellAttributes
                }
            }
        }
    }

    let contentWidth = Double(collectionView!.numberOfItemsInSection(0)) * CELL_WIDTH
    let contentHeight = Double(collectionView!.numberOfSections()) * CELL_HEIGHT
    self.contentSize = CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight)

}

override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

    var attributesInRect = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

    for cellAttributes in cellAttrDict.values {
        if CGRectIntersectsRect(rect, cellAttributes.frame) {
            attributesInRect.append(cellAttributes)
        }
    }

    return attributesInRect
}

override func layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    return cellAttrDict[indexPath]!
}

override func shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange(newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

How about a traditional flowLayout, with Swipe Gesture Recognizers to trigger the change in direction?

```
var layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

//Hook to two Swipe Gesture Recognizers - Up and Down
@IBAction func verticalSwipe(sender: AnyObject) {
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Vertical
    self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout = layout
}

//Hook to two Swipe Gesture Recognizers - Left and Right    
@IBAction func horizontalSwipe(sender: AnyObject) {
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Horizontal
    self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout = layout
}
```

Comment: Would't that change the whole collectionview behavior ?

Comment: I'll admit I haven't gotten it working yet, but it seems like since we can set that one variable `UICollectionViewScrollDirection`, this would be the direction I'd look.

Answer (score 0):

I'd subclass UICollectionViewFlowlayout, not UICollectionViewLayout, and then use a supplementary view for the y-axis vertical swipe labels.  So, for example, if the user swipes down they see more channels.

The horizontal swipe could show time of day with a supplementary view for the header labels showing time.

Use layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind to ensure that the y (vertical) and x (horizontal) titles are always visible (update their frames based on collection view contentOffset).

To the user this will look like they are swiping down to see more channels and swiping horizontally to see earlier/later in the day.

Hope this helps.  My use cases are around calendar and booking applications and this approach works well for that.